# Issue deploying dacpac on SQL Server 2008 R2 created using VS13 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2, xml-namespaces, database-project, dacpac

I have a Database Project in Visual Studio 2013 which I use to create a dacpac file and deploy it on SQL Servers using SQL Server Management Studio. I can successfully deploy the dacpac on SQL Server 2012 but when I try to deploy it on SQL Server 2008 R2, I get the following error message when selecting the DAC package:

```
<DacType xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/Serialization/2012/02'> was not expected. (es3ttafd)
```

I have selected "SQL Server 2008" as Target Platform under Project Settings but this does not seem to modify the namespace. When I unpack the dacpac, I can see that this namespace exists inside DacMetadata.xml, model.xml and Origin.xml files.

Is there anything I can do to stop including that namespace in the dacpac (or change it to the correct one?) in order to allow me to deploy it on an SQL Server 2008? I can successfully publish the project through VS on the SQL Server but I want to be able to create a dac package and deploy it on other servers as well, using the wizard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're using an old version of SQL Server Management Studio to deploy to SQL Server 2008.  I'd suggest downloading the latest SSMS (available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) and using that to publish.

Alternately, the most recent version of the Data-Tier Application Framework (available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53876) includes SqlPackage.exe, which can be used to publish a dacpac file, like so:

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:publish /tcs:"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=true" /sf:C:\project\mydb.dacpac
```

See documentation for SqlPackage.exe here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanks Steven. I tried using SSMS16 and it worked. I had tried SSMS14 before posting here but it still didn't work so I assumed that it had nothing to do with the version of SSMS but with the DB project's output from VS. Isn't there a fix however for the the DacType namespace that gets created like that from VS (although the target platform is set to SQL Server 2008)?

Comment: Good to hear that it's working now.  I'm not sure why SSMS 2014 would give an error about that xml namespace.  The context is that the SQL Server 2008 tools produced dacpac files that have a file format that's different from the SQL Server 2012 (and newer) tools.  The old tools will not recognize the newer file format, but SSMS 2014 should have no issue with the dacpac file format produced by VS2013.